# Is there a way to only do a partial function check using the devtools function check()?

Tags: r, devtools

I'm writing a package and as I add more functions to it, running the `check()` function is taking more and more time to run. This is fine if I am checking a whole new function or set of functions I've written, but if I'm only fixing something minor from the previous instance of `check()` its rather time consuming. Is there a way to only do a partial check of the error, warning, or note that was thrown or should I just work on my patience?

Comment: Maybe write a test instead?

Comment: But if the issue is internal, like properly defining dependent functions, or making sure the documentation is formatted correctly, will a test be able to effectively check it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. Just focused on this: **Is there a way to only do a partial check of the error, warning, or note that was thrown or**